# tunnel-bastion-client service cannot start

Tags: postgresql, amazon-ec2, terraform, psql, ssh-tunnel

I am trying to establish tunnel bastion connection between two ec2 instance. The client side is allowing Lambda to reach server side RDS. I checked the client side ec2 and find the service tunnel-bastion-client cannot start.

```
Aug 17 23:07:49 ip-172-31-25-38 systemd[1]: tunnel-bastion-client.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is>
Aug 17 23:07:49 ip-172-31-25-38 systemd[1]: Stopped Maintain connection with tunnel bastion.
Aug 17 23:07:49 ip-172-31-25-38 systemd[1]: Started Maintain connection with tunnel bastion.
Aug 17 23:07:50 ip-172-31-25-38 ssh[186032]: Host key verification failed.
Aug 17 23:07:50 ip-172-31-25-38 systemd[1]: tunnel-bastion-client.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=>
Aug 17 23:07:50 ip-172-31-25-38 systemd[1]: tunnel-bastion-client.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'
```

For some reason, the tunnel-bastion-client service cannot be started manually. I can connect RDS from server side ec2. So, it is not the database issue.

```
# psql -h xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxx.us-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com -p 5432 postgres
Password: 
psql (10.18 (Ubuntu 10.18-0ubuntu0.18.04.1), server 11.9)
WARNING: psql major version 10, server major version 11.
         Some psql features might not work.
SSL connection (protocol: TLSv1.2, cipher: ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, bits: 256, compression: off)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=>
```

I used the terraform to standup the both ec2 and grabbing from parameter store. Please help me find out where exactly is the issue. Appreciate in advance.

Answer (score 0):

work around, execute "ExecStart" line from /etc/systemd/system/tunnel-bastion-client.service file.